# std::basic_istream::ignore hangs if delim MSB is set

Tags: c++, gcc, stream, libstdc++

Given the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::stringstream str;
  str.put('a');
  str.put('\x80');
  str.put('a');

  str.ignore(32, '\x80'); // hangs
  std::cout << str.tellg() << "\n";
}
```

If compiled with gcc, the marked line hangs, assembly step through indicates an infinite loop. I tried GCC 5.4, 6.3, 8.2, 9.2, on different OSes, the result is the same.
On wandbox, also tried clang (that is probably coming with libc++ instead of libstdc++), it terminates fine.

It only happens if the second argument of ignore is a character with MSB set, and if there's at least one character before and after in the stream. Is this an error in libstdc++, or does the standard prohibit non-ascii delimiters?

Comment: If `char` is signed I guess you have UB due to signed integer overflow. Try: `std::basic_stringstream<unsigned char> str;` and it'll probably work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: using `CharT = unsigned char` indeed works. Even if I pass `char{'\x80'}` to ignore, there are no errors or warnings, I don't see where the overflow happens. On the other hand, I suspect that sign extension happens (as ignore really takes int_type and not char), that could cause some issues.
Passing ignore an unsigned char also works.

Comment: Putting `\x80` in `put( char_type ch );` when `char_type` is a signed `char` makes a signed integer overflow if I'm not mistaken - but even if I change it to a negative literal, like -128, -127 or -2 in both the `put` and the `ignore` it'll spin forever. The only negative value that works seems to be `std::char_traits<char>::eof()` (-1). [g++/clang++ playground](https://godbolt.org/z/LSqKgZ)

Comment: It's worth noting that even though the `libc++` version doesn't spin, it reports `eof()` instead of the position in the stream where the negative value was inserted.

Comment: Another finding: `std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::put` does not have overloads for `signed char`  or `unsigned char`, but `g++` also works if you use `std::basic_stringstream<signed char>`  and `-128` https://godbolt.org/z/ZbvZeg - `clang++` refuses to compile that.